# Capacitor (build.gradle does not exist/operation not permitted) React app to Android can't build

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, gradle, capacitor

I can't build my react webapp to android using capacitor (never done it before). However, I successfully did so to ios.

I've tried to sync gradle manually from android studio (file > sync project with gradle files), but still no luck.

These are the errors (steps to reproduce are included below):

> 12.41 Gradle sync failed: /spacex-launches/node_modules/@capacitor/android/capacitor/build.gradle
>   (Operation not permitted) (54 s 634 ms)

The main question here is, **(Operation not permitted)**
I've tried to allow all access for everything (read and write) for everyone for every file in the folder. Still, again, no luck.

The commands I ran to reproduce these errors:

1. `npx cap init`
2. `npx cap app` (then I picked android)
3. `npx cap open android` (it tried to sync and then gave me the errors above; thus build is not possible).

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Have you done cordova settings?

Comment: @keikai Nope. iOS worked out of the box kind of thing, so I expected android to be the same :\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out, opening the android folder manually using Android Studio, weirdly enough **fixed it**.

Comment: That worked for me also, just restarting Android Studio.  At that point, it downloaded and installed gradle correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your source code is in a remote repository somewhere, try a fresh install in another directory. First, update the Ionic CLI.

`npm i -g @ionic/cli@latest`

`git clone https://.../your-app.git`

`cd ./your-app`

`npm i`

`ionic build`

`ionic cap add android`

`ionic cap open android`

Note you don't need to run `npx cap init` again. Since the iOS build is working, Capacitor is already installed in your project.

If you still can't build, ensure your environment is set up correctly. This can vary whether you are on Mac or Windows. The Capacitor docs provide [guidance](https://capacitor.ionicframework.com/docs/android).